# Design a lowpass filter Butterwoth prototype in Octave

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, octave, butterworth

Do you know what is wrong with this code?
I am building a filter with Butterworth prototype and I do not know where I made a mistake.

```
Apass = 0.6;  % dB 
Astop = 16;   % dB
omega_pass = 1; 
Gstop = -16;
omega_stop = 5;
OMEGA = omega_stop/omega_pass;

n = ceil( log10( (10^(-Gstop/10) - 1)  / ( (10^(-Gpass/ 10) -1 ) )) / ( 2 * ( log10(OMEGA))) );

p = zeros([1 n]);
for k = 1:n
    p(k) = exp( ((i*pi)/(2*n)) * (2 * k + n - 1));
end;
```

Result of standardized filter (1Hz):
[image: Result of standardized filter (1Hz)]

Now I convert the filter to suppress the 130kHz+ frequency.

```
% 132000 Hz = 132kHz
p_lp = zeros([1 n]); %lp for LowPass, p for poles
for k = 1:n
    p_lp(k) = p(k) * (130000);
end;

pkg load signal;
z = []; % zeros
k = 1.6*10^10; % signal amplification
[num, den] = zp2tf(z, p_lp, k)
sys_lp = tf(num, den)
y_lp = filter(num, den, modulated);
[osX_lp, P1_lp] = computeFFT(y_lp, fs);
```

And the result is:
[image: result]

FFT of filtered signal:
[image]

I know, that the plot do not show anything. There is error below.
I think the filter is not filtering correctly. Do you get any idea to fix it?

also the error:

```
 ﬐਀warning: opengl_renderer: data values greater than float capacity.  (1) Scale data, or (2) Use gnuplot
>> warning: opengl_renderer: data values greater than float capacity.  (1) Scale data, or (2) Use gnuplot
warning: opengl_renderer: data values greater than float capacity.  (1) Scale data, or (2) Use gnuplot
warning: opengl_renderer: data values greater than float capacity.  (1) Scale data, or (2) Use gnuplot
warning: opengl_renderer: data values greater than float capacity.  (1) Scale data, or (2) Use gnuplot
warning: opengl_renderer: data values greater than float capacity.  (1) Scale data, or (2) Use gnuplot
```

computeFFT is my function which returns x axis and single-sided spectrum

```
function [osX, P1] = computeFFT(data, freq)
    L = length(data);
    % fft
    transform = fft(data);
    osX = 4;
    P1 = 5;
    % two-sided spectrum
    P2 = abs(transform/L);
    osX = freq*(0:(length(P2)/2))/length(P2);
##    % single-sided spectrum
    P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
    P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
endfunction
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered to ask that question at [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions) as this is rather a question of signal processing than programming in general.

Comment: `error: 'Gpass' undefined near line ...`  either this is not a standalone example that can be copy/pasted and debugged for us to help you specifically, or it is and your specific error (at least in the first instance) is simply that you're missing some variable definitions.